# Regex: pattern repeated capture – delimit the matching at the end of the pattern - non capture group and lookaheads negative example

Tags: regex

I wish to match the end of my text and for it I have to match all the characters and the line breaks.

But I must exclude the beginning of the next capture!

What I want is to delimit the end of the pattern where the next pattern begins.

I tried to replace

```
[^-]
```

by something like

```
(?!-{2}\\*{3})
```

It doesn't work !

So I want to capture the number and I want to capture the whole paragraph (some text) between (--*** x ***)

[image: Regex capture]

Comment: Can you show examples of what's the desired match after the change?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking for. Can you clarify what your expected input and expected output are?

Comment: I juste want to capture the entire 'some text', the whole paragraph. tanks

Comment: Matching differs from capturing and your whole story is about replacing. Would you mind re-phrasing your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found exactly what I wanted! :)

```
--\*{3}([^!*]*)\*{3}((?:(?!-{2}\*{3})(?:\n|.))*)
```

I must group what I want and what I don't want.
For that I must use a 'non-capture group' and a 'negative lookahead':

```
(?!nowant)(?:want)
```

Then I must use a 'non-capture group' to agregate the matching:

```
(?:(?!nowant)(?:want))
```

After, I add the quantifier '*'

```
(?:(?!nowant)(?:want))*
```

And finally, I add a 'capture group':

```
((?:(?!nowant)(?:want))*)
```

So here is the regex:

```
((?:(?!-{2}\*{3})(?:\n|.))*)
```

You can see the complete Regex [here :

https://regex101.com/r/xJ0gC6/2](https://regex101.com/r/xJ0gC6/2)

Comment: In fact, regex101 count in my case only 168 steps, and this solution count 2317 (2334 before the edit). So, it is nearly 14 times "faster" :)

Comment: @DidierAupest: The number of steps does not directly mean a pattern is fast or slow, but definitely here the discrepancy is huge.

Comment: I tested and I don't think Didier's answer is the best, sorry.

Comment: Anybody can explain me why I have a negative quotation ?

Answer (score 2):

Using this regex seems to work:

```
--\*{3}([\d]*)\*{3}(((?!-).*\n)*)
```

1st Capturing group: The digit inside the stars.

2nd Capturing group: The text between the "headers"

3rd Capturing group: The last line of the paragraph.

A link with the regex tested:
https://regex101.com/r/xJ0gC6/1